# How to preview of html content in A4 pages format with dynamic content changes with fixed page size in angular

Tags: html, css, angular

Unable to send the excess data from one page to another page.

I tried with Adding Child Element if content touches the bottom of the current page then new child element will be created, but unable to move the excess content to the newly created child element.

Comment: it's very hard to read... it seems you are having issues with content breaking or not the page but you talked about _"excess data"_ and _"unable to move content"_ and it's a very obscure scenario. Please can you share further details?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.